# How to plot data that is separated into multiple categories using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, facet, multivalue

A market survey on consumer satisfaction when using two cleaning products (Product A and Product B) was separated according to room (Kitchen, Bathroom, Bedroom), frequency of use (Daily, Weekly, Monthly) and product bottle size (Small, Medium, Large).

I thought the best way to represent these results is column plots. However, I think there are better ways to represent these results, so I come here to ask for suggestions for a better graphical representation, as I am not very satisfied with column plots.

In MWE the data is arranged ascending, but with real data, the different column sizes make the plot visually very polluted.

```
library(ggplot2)

Product <- c("Product A", "Product B")
Place <- c("Kitchen", "Bathroom", "Bedroom")
Bottle_size <- c("Small", "Medium", "Large")
Frequency <- c("Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly")

DF <- expand.grid(Bottle_size = Bottle_size,
                  Place = Place,
                  Frequency = Frequency,
                  Product = Product)

DF$Consumer_Approval <- seq(from = 10,
                            to = 100,
                            by = (100-10)/53)

ggplot(data = DF,
       aes(x = Frequency,
           y = Consumer_Approval)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Bottle_size),
           position = "dodge") +
  facet_grid(Product ~ Place)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSyHO.png)

The real data is something like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX6i4.png)

Comment: this is really a matter of taste. In my opinion, since you want to compare the 2 products, it could be better to use `fill=Product` and `facet_grid(Bottle_size ~ Place)` thus consumer approval for products appears directly comparable, but as I said it is a matter of personal taste. I think the column plot is right since you have a categorical x-variable and a continuous y-one.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be a lollipop chart, where the height of the lollipop shows the *difference* between the consumer rating for product A and product B. This allows a quick visual estimate of the preferred product in a given setting:

```r
ProdA <- split(DF, Product)[[1]]
ProdB <- split(DF, Product)[[2]]
DF <- dplyr::left_join(ProdA, ProdB, c("Bottle_size", "Place", "Frequency"))
DF$AvsB <- DF$Consumer_Approval.x - DF$Consumer_Approval.y

ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = Frequency, y = AvsB, color = Bottle_size)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = AvsB, ymax = 0), position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 2) +
  ylim(-100, 100) +
  facet_grid(.~Place) +
  labs(y = "Prefers Product B <- No preference  -> Prefers Product A")
```

[image]